# How to make the new added item sit under the existed id in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem where the new added item created a new id instead of sit under the existed id

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jutxv.png)

The picture above show that the yellow highlighted id is the existed id. The red on is the new added item. I have problem where the added item created a new id instead of sitting on the existed id in the highlighted id.

Result that I want to achieve is. I wanted the new added item sit under the highlighted id instead of creating the new id.

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart");
     private void addCart() {

            final String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String cust_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            final String pid = intent.getStringExtra("pid");
            String keyB = intent.getStringExtra("keyB");
            String name = pname.getText().toString().trim();
            String category = pcategory.getText().toString().trim();
            String price = pprice.getText().toString().trim();
            String size = psize.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            String quantity = pquantity.getText().toString().trim();

            String image = intent.getStringExtra("pro_image");

            final Cart cart = new Cart(id, pid, cust_id, keyB, name, price, image, category, quantity, size);
            databaseReference.child("Cust List").child(cust_id).child(id).child(pid).setValue(cart) //table and primary key
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                       databaseReference.child("PS List").child(cust_id).child(id).child(pid).setValue(cart).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                           @Override
                                                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "add Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                   AddToCart.super.onBackPressed();
                                                               }
                                                           }
                                                       });

                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time,after **cust_id** when you added data in your database, a new id is generated. Thats's mean databaseReference from **cust_id** is always same, after **cust_id** it changed. So, you need to keep databaseReference unchanged from here,

```
 databaseReference.child("Cust List").child(cust_id).child(id)
```

When you use **.push** keyword, it always generated a new id. But you need to keep it always same like **cust_id**.So, if you use same reference from **----.child(id)**, when you add data in database, i think the problem will solve.

Comment: what kind of changes should i make? I use the same references like the databaseReference

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I don't really understand which part of the code that I should change

Comment: You need to keep ---.child(id) reference always same name or id (like cust_id). For testing purpose, i say you can put a default name or id which is unchanged .Like -
databaseReference.child("Cust List").child(cust_id).child(here put unchanged value)

Comment: You uesd .push value. When you use .push value, every time it give you a new id. A new id means it changed every time when you add data. But you need to keep id remain unchange. You can see your cust_id, is always same. Like cust_id you also need to keep .child(id) remain unchanged. You can also see, your cust_id is always remain same, for that, when you add data, it comes under cust_id. So,like cust_id, if you keep your --.child(Id) always same and when you add data it comes what you expect

Comment: I have try like u suggested sir I tried to put the ` databaseReference.child("Cust List").child(cust_id).child(abc)` it works, but I don't want to set the value. I want the the id to be generated to make sure that it will not get duplicated with other table. Because I have PS table that will store the same information with Cart table. It just that PS table will have its own function .

Comment: Im creating a cart function, when user cart is empty then when user add item to their cart it will generate the cart id. later user wants to add more item into their cart. and there the problems come. instead of using the same cart id it keeps generate the new id. I don't quite sure on how to fix that problems.

Comment: I can't understand properly. Firebase database is NoSql database. So, you don't need to see is there any duplication value or not. It works like child-parent. What you want, for that, you must need to keep same reference from --.chil(id) and you can't use .push keyword because it always give you a new id. When database reference get a new id it added to under cust_id.

Comment: You need to use always same cart id. May be you can use it as a default or your set value. When you add new product in your cart, it always gives you new id, .push keyword always give you a new id. Just think your cust_id, it always same. Like cust_id , you can take a id, which is remain unchange.